# How do you use mvc views to fill bootstrap tabs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, layout, razor

I am building an MVC application and am trying to use twitter bootstrap to build a responsive ui.  I have setup my navigation as follows:

```
  <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">Sell</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">Customers</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane5" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane6" data-toggle="tab">Help</a></li> 
        </ul>                                                 
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane">
                page 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Panels 2-6 are omitted to save space -->

    </div>
</div>
```

My question is what is optimal solution. 
1) To find a way, to put this in a Razor Layout and load the individual panes as RenderSections
2) To scrap the Razor Layout and just apply the navigation to all content pages

Comment: A layout is indeed a good choice for this.  Copying and pasting the navigation into every page would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would Probably recommend using RenderPage vs RenderSection as it would appear that you will always have the same content rendered in each panel. So most of your work will be done in your _Layout.cshtml. Your body is going to look like this:

```
  <body>
    <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">Sell</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Products</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">Customers</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#pane5" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#pane6" data-toggle="tab">Help</a></li> 
    </ul>                                                 
</div>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Then you are going to have an Index.cshtml which will act as your landing page and it will look something like this:

```
<div>
   @Html.Partial("ViewName")
   // Reapeat for each tab
</div>
```

Then is each tab partial you will have your content for the tab:

```
<div class="tab-content">
     <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane">
          page 1
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So each "view" would have the divs with the panel content or would you just have that one landing page with all the panel content?

Comment: @mattweston is your tab content going to be static or would it be dynamic?

Comment: We're looking at building a POS app similar to the one at www.vendhq.com.  I'm trying to build the navigation where we have a main navbar at the top and a sub navbar that loads depending upon the "tab" selected.

Comment: @mattweston so that would imply that each tab will have dynamic content vs being static HTML

Comment: Correct, I think I have a solution.  Based on the code you presented, I think I will put my panel divs in the "landing" page and insert my sub menus as partial views inside those divs.  I will then have a RenderPage for the content for each panel and load the content via jquery.

Comment: I'm actually thinking now that a Partial View might be preferred over a RenderPage.

Comment: @mattweston I was just going to suggest that as each panel is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using layouts. Here are the basic steps:

1. Create a layout that includes your navbar. Put the layout in the /Views/Shared folder. (e.g. _LayoutMain.cshtml)

   ```
   <body>
   <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="active"><a href="#pane1Link">Dashboard</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#pane2Link">Sell</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#pane3Link">Products</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#pane4Link">Customers</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#pane5Link">Settings</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#pane6Link">Help</a></li> 
   </ul>                                                 
   </div>
       @RenderBody()
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
   ```
2. Create a template (optionally with a controller action) for each nav bar item (Sell, Products, Customers, etc.)
3. In each template, reference your layout like so:

   ```
   @{
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
   }
   ```
4. Then add the following javascript code to the main layout page. This code actively selects which nav bar item you've currently clicked:

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var pathname = $(location).attr('pathname');
           $('a[href="' + pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
       });
   </script>
   ```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can nest as many layouts as you want. So for example, you could have a main navbar and within one of those pages you could have another navbar (such as tabs/pills) using the same approach.

This might be helpful too:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/164/nested-layout-pages-with-razor.